# Where can I find informations about iOS image file naming in official manual?

Tags: ios, image, naming, manual

Some of naming is described here:

http://www.weston-fl.com/blog/?p=840/

However, I want to check this from official manual. Where can I find this info from official manual?

Answer (score 2):

The official Apple document is [Technical Q&A QA1686 “App Icons on iPad and iPhone”](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html).