# ios - iphone and ipad image (not icon!) names

Tags: ios, iphone, image, ipad

so i'd like the image names for iphone and ipad. There is a lot of info about  icon naming - see here [for icons, for example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9356874/1061426). The link for apple's  doco on icons [is here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html).

I want to know about images though. Does anyone have a list of all the valid iphone/ipad image sizes, and the file naming convention for each of those sizes? From ipad 1 to ipad-whatever-it-is-now, and from iphone-1 to iphone-6+

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18976412/launch-screens-supporting-ios6-and-ios7-forced-to-splash-screen

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26029440/ios8-icons-sizes-and-names-for-icons-and-launch-image

Comment: @jlanisdev these appear to be for icons and launch (splash) pages. Is there something on images - you know, the things like the images for buttons, the images for backgrounds?

Comment: You can use any name you like for the images you place in buttons and backgrounds.  You can use `@2x` and `@3x` suffix to indicate retina and HD retina images, but it is simpler to use an image catalog

Comment: @Paulw11 i'm using titanium, which is sadly silent on the issue. i figure i'm going to have to name the images appropriately - is there some resource for naming *images* for ios? (i'm assuming "image catalogue" is some x-code api thing)

Comment: If "button.png" was your base image (say a 32x32 button image) then you would create a 64x64 version and call it "button@2x.png" and a 96x96 image and call it "button@3x.png".  When you refer to "button.png" iOS will look for the `@3x` & `@2x` versions and use them if appropriate